# GSON act differently for the same object if it's wrapped?

Tags: java, gson

Short story : 
I have `List<A> list`. If I use `gson.toJson(list)` - works fine. 
If I have `ListContainer(list)` , then `gson.toJson(listContainer)` returns a list with empty objects. Why?  How can I solve it?

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GsonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GsonTest();
    }

    public GsonTest() {

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        List<BasicInterface> kws = new ArrayList<BasicInterface>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            BasicInterface kw = new BasicInterfaceImpl("string_" + i);
            kws.add(kw);
        }

        System.out.print(gson.toJson(kws));
        /** Prints: [{"expression":"string_0"},{"expression":"string_1"},{"expression":"string_2"}] */

        Container kwc = new Container(kws);

        System.out.print(gson.toJson(kwc));
        /** Prints: {"list":[{},{},{}]}  */

    }
}

public class Container {

    private List<BasicInterface> list;

    public Container(List<BasicInterface> kws) {
        this.list = kws;
    }

    public List<BasicInterface> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}

public interface BasicInterface {

    String getExpression();
}

public class BasicInterfaceImpl implements BasicInterface {
    private String expression;

    public BasicInterfaceImpl(String expression) {
        this.expression = expression;
    }

    @Override
    public String getExpression() {
        return expression;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix is: use **BasicInterfaceImpl** instead of **BasicInterface** when declaring variable and methods in **Container**.

Why? Don't know. I spent a hour debugging GSON sources, but can't say for sure yet :-)

Comment: Yep , I figured something like this already - another workaround is to use BasicInterface[] instead of List<BasicInterface> , works too.